# Setting option in select dropdown based on data-attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select dropdown containing a list of countries looking something like this:

```
<select name="countryCode" id="countryCode">
<option data-countryCode="GB" value="44" Selected>UK (+44)</option>
<option data-countryCode="US" value="1">USA (+1)</option>
<optgroup label="Other countries">
    <option data-countryCode="DZ" value="213">Algeria (+213)</option>
    <option data-countryCode="AD" value="376">Andorra (+376)</option>
</optgroup>
</select>
```

I then look up the user's country using ipinfo.io and would like to set the selected option based on the returned country and the data-countryCode attribute. I have tried some different approaches, but I simply cannot get it to work.

I have created a jsfiddle with the country-selector and the lookup:
http://jsfiddle.net/E7fBk/

How do I set the drop-down to show the user's country ?

thanks

Thomas

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
$(function () {
    $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
        $('#countryCode option[data-countryCode="' + response.country + '"]').prop('selected', true)
    }, "jsonp");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kZhdP)

Answer (score 2):

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/E7fBk/2/)

```
$(function () {
    $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
        $('#countryCode option[data-countryCode="' + response.country + '"]').prop('selected', true)
    }, "jsonp");
});
```

or

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/E7fBk/3/)

```
$(function () {
    $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
        $('#countryCode').val($('#countryCode [data-countryCode="' + response.country + '"]').val());
    }, "jsonp");
});
```